# Pass argument to view with reverse url django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
url = reverse("school_management:school-management-list", args=(student.id,))
```

Hi, i am using django reverse url, here i am getting output as

```
'/school/student/.2979/school-details/'
```

I am not getting why **.** is included here in output?

The url i have defined is shown below

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('school', SchoolManagementView, basename="school-management")

app_name = "school_management"
urlpatterns = [
    path('student/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

And the view is

```
class SchoolManagementView(ViewSet):

 @action(detail=True,
            methods=["patch"],
            url_path='school-details')
 def update_school_details(self, request, pk):
      pass
```

Comment: How is the URL defined?

Comment: I have used viewsets so i have defined the routers for that @deceze

Comment: And you didn’t override the viewset method somehow, and `student.id` does not contain a period…?

Comment: Yes i have overrided please check the whole code above. @deceze